# Проверка существования объекта c#

Tags: c#, json

Добрый день ,
провожу десериализацию json , если один из пунктов поиска отсутствует то появляется ошибка , 
например если в json отсутствует пункт description то выкинет с ошибкой
string description = a["offer"]["description"].ToString();

как проверить существует ли  объект или же данная информация не указана не ловя ошибку ?(try catch замедляют использовать бы не хотелось)
Спасибо

```
JObject a = JObject.Parse(autoinf.GetcodeAutoUrl(url));
```

Comment: Какой тип имеет `a`?

Comment: что такое `a["offer"]["description"]`, или как оно по вашему должно работать? "offer" это элемент перечислимого типа??

Comment: `string description = a["offer"]?["description"]?.ToString();` - так не работает? (Добавил элвис-оператор ?./?[])

Comment: @АндрейNOP - это вполне можно опубликовать ответом.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а это сработает? Я просто мало экспериментировал с JSON.NET... В документации про индексатор тоже ничего не нашел, придется пробовать

Answer (score 1):

Кроме хорошего способа, предложенного в комментариях, можно использовать Json.Linq:

```
var description = a["offer"].Children<JProperty>()
    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "description");

if (description != null)
    Console.WriteLine(description.Value);
```

Методом `Children` получаем коллекцию нужных типов и далее находим нужное нам свойство по имени. Этот способ можно применять для получения любых возможных типов json.

Answer (score 1):

Т.к. при отсутствии ключа, указанного в индексаторе, `JObject` возвращает `null`, самый просто способ - воспользоваться оператором `?.`:

```
string description = a["offer"]["description"]?.ToString();
```

В этом случае вместо вызова метода `ToString()` будет сразу возвращен `null`, при необходимости вы можете это проверить (`if (description == null) ...`) или оставить как есть (если `null` является допустимым значением).

Так же, если в случае отсутствия ключа вам необходимо использовать какое-то значение по умолчанию, удобно использовать оператор `??`:

```
string description = a["offer"]["description"]?.ToString() ?? "Описание отсутствует";
```

Если также может не существовать элемента `offer`, можно еще и оператор `?[]` "прикрутить":

```
string description = a["offer"]?["description"]?.ToString();
```

Литература по теме:

1. [Операторы с условием NULL](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)
2. [?? Оператор](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator)